# How to remove the Horizontal Scroll bar in <p:dataTable>

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable, scrollbar

I am trying to hide the horizontal scrollbar in .
I tried many solutions  but it doesn't seems to work.
The Solution that I tried is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795004/remove-horizontal-scroll-bar-on-background-div)
Here is my code used that I used in XHTML

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:form id="commentsform">
        <p:outputPanel id="commenttable">
            <p:dataTable id="commentsdt" var="row" stickyHeader="true"
                value="#{bean.displayCommentsDetailsList}"
                selection="#{bean.selectedComments}"
                rowKey="#{row.commentDate}" rows="20" paginator="true"
                paginatorPosition="bottom" rowIndexVar="index"
                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150" style="width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;"
                rowStyleClass="#{row.changeFieldFlg==true ? 'highlight' : null}">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGrid columnClasses="alignRight">
                        <p:commandButton
                            disabled="#{bean.editCmdActionflg == false}"
                            actionListener="#{bean.addComments}"
                            update="commentsdt :SystemDetailsinfoForm:line :growl :error"
                            partialSubmit="true" title="Add Row.." icon="ui-icon-plusthick"
                            styleClass="iconButton" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>

                <p:column width="160" headerText="Date" style="width:150px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.commentDate}" style="width:150px" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column width="160" headerText="Author" style="width:150px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.author}" style="width:150px" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column width="100" headerText="Deliverable" style="width:90px"
                    rendered="#{bean.selectedChoice == '2'}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.delivName}"
                        rendered="#{bean.selectedChoice == '2'}"
                        style="width:90px" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Comments">
                    <div align="left">
                        <h:outputText value="#{row.comments}"
                            rendered="#{row.editableflg==false}"></h:outputText>
                        <p:inputTextarea value="#{row.comments}"
                            style="width:98%;float:left" rendered="#{row.editableflg==true}">
                        </p:inputTextarea>
                    </div>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition><br/>
```

I tried using  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden; to hide the horzontal scrollbar but none of them seems to get applied to the datatable.
Please let me know your suggestions to resolve this issue

Comment: I resolved the above issue by adding .ui-datatable-scrollable-body {
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
 overflow-x: hidden !important;
} to my default style sheet.But this change works for the above table but that same change is impacting the other datatables where it removes all the horizontal scrollbars,since its a generic one.How can I apply this change to the specific datatable calling the stylesheet.

Answer (score 8):

I just made a custom style  for the `<p:dataTable>` and called that style in the .

The style I wrote was

```
.mystyle.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body{
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

And I called the styleclass **styleClass="mystyle"**  in the `<p:dataTable>` which I have given below

```
<p:dataTable id="commentsdt" var="row" stickyHeader="true"
                value="#{systemDetailsBean.displayCommentsDetailsList}"
                selection="#{systemDetailsBean.selectedComments}" rowKey="#{row.commentDate}"
                rows="20" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                rowIndexVar="index"
                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                scrollHeight="150" scrollable="true" style="width:100%;"  styleClass="mystyle"
                rowStyleClass="#{row.changeFieldFlg==true ? 'highlight' : null}">
```

Comment: In my case worked - `.mystyle .ui-datatable-scrollable-view .ui-datatable-scrollable-body{
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a vertical scroll bar, because one of the styles used within the cell defined a non-zero `padding`.

Redefining style with zero `padding` the scroll bar disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 20 px in height, in my case I added in the width, as I needed it on the width.
So my div container :

```
  .container {
height: 100%;
width: calc(100% + 20px);}
```

I used this trick because I want only the vertical scrollbar hidden, and unfortunately, I don't know how to hide only the vertical one on the primeng data-table. And I hope it's helpful for ya

Comment: the already working solution you're mentioning didn't work for me that's why I'm proposing this one ;)